# what is the wrong with this PHP function?

Tags: php

can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this function?

I wrote this this function to get errors from $reg_errors array and to use those errors in different place in the same script.

```
function testimonialErrors ($reg_errors) {
    if ( !empty($reg_errors) ) {
            foreach ( $reg_errors AS $error) {
                echo "<li>$error</li>";
            }                                       
    }
    return $error; 
}
```

Then I called that function like this..

```
if ( !empty($reg_errors) ) {
    echo '<div class="error">
                <img src="images/error.png" />
                <h3>Errors,</h3>
                <ul>';
                echo testimonialErrors($reg_errors);
        echo '</ul>
            </div>';
}
```

But this code is not working.

UPDATE : this is my new code

```
function tesimonialErrors ($reg_errors) {
    if ( !empty($reg_errors) ) {
            foreach ( $reg_errors AS $error) {
                echo "<li>$error</li>";
            }                                       
    }
    return $error; 
}
```

And called it like this

```
if ( !empty($reg_errors) ) {
    echo '<div class="error">
                <img src="images/error.png" />
                <h3>Errors,</h3>
                <ul>';
                tesimonialErrors($reg_errors);
        echo '</ul>
            </div>';
}
```

Comment: use global $reg_errors or $GLOBALS['reg_errors']

Comment: @devOp no he doesn't. The echo is already inside the function. Your function can't see `$reg_errors`/

Comment: Explain "it doesn't work"

Comment: Learn what a *variable scope* is: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I tried echoing function but not working..echo tesimonialErrors();

Comment: oh.. why I get down votes for my question?

Comment: What is the exact html output of that code?

Comment: when calling that function there is nothing in my html

Comment: @jeroen Actually what has happened there? I am trying this for hours to fix. but still no luck

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). At this moment, `$reg_errors` is not defined in the scope of your function. You could pass it to the function:

```
function tesimonialErrors ($reg_errors) {
  ...
```

and call it like:

```
tesimonialErrors($reg_errors);
```

Comment: And don't forget to put it in the call ... :)

Comment: Better this way than using globals!

Comment: @jeroen I tried it but not working. Check I updated my question

Comment: @Tharanga Nuwan You should leave your original code and put your edits below for clarity. Apart from that, the edited code seems about right, what does `$reg_errors` contain and what is the exact html output?

Comment: @Tharanga Nuwan By the way, you should not `echo` the output of your function (just call it, you are echoing in the function itself), nor do you need to return the last `$error` value; that will mess up your list / html.

Comment: @jeroen I printed $reg_errors then I got this - Array ( [name] => Name : This field is required. [email] => Email Address : This field is required. [membertype] => Membership Type : This field is required. [0] => No file selected [write-testimonials] => Testimonial : This field is required. )

Comment: @Tharanga Nuwan That should work, just get rid of the extra `echo` in your main code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this?

```
if ( !empty($reg_errors) ) {
    echo '<div class="error">
            <img src="images/error.png" />
            <h3>Errors,</h3>
            <ul>
               <li>';
    echo implode('</li><li>', $reg_errors);
    echo '    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Akam pointed out, $reg_errors is in the global scope so you need to use either `global $reg_errors;` or `$GLOBALS['reg_errors']`.

Also I'd suggest changing the function name `tesimonialErrors` to proper English (I'd assume that would be `testimonialErrors`). Otherwise, The Next Guy might end up posting it on TDWTF.

Answer (score -1):

```
function testimonialErrors ($reg_errors) {
    if ( !empty($reg_errors) ) {
            foreach ( $reg_errors AS $error) {
                echo "<li>$error</li>";
            }                                       
    }
    return $error;  // ****remove return statement**** 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `global $reg_errors;` to your function.

```
function testimonialErrors () {
    global $reg_errors;
    if (!empty($reg_errors)) {
        foreach ($reg_errors as $error) {
            echo "<li>$error</li>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Globals are evil! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions have a read :)

Comment: @Mez: why? could you send a reference?

Comment: @Mez: I'd agree in principle but the OP didn't seem like they were likely or willing to change that much of their code.